# Why is the image overflowing outside of the wrapper?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to clear the float with a div after the floated image but the image is still outside of the wrapper

This method to clearfix is usually effective - what am I doing wrong?

```html
<!Doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #wrapper {
      width: 600px;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }
    #wrapper p {
      float: left;
      width: 200px;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
    #wrapper img {
      float: right;
    }
    #wrapper .clearfix {
      overflow: auto;
      border: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">

    <p>
      This image is taller than the element containing it, and it's floated, so it's overflowing outside of its container!
    </p>

    <img src="picture.jpg" />

    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's not a clearfix. `overflow: auto` must be on `#wrapper`. The clearfix trick you are searching is for `clear: both` on `.clearfix`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use an overflow method for clearing floats, then you should set `overflow: auto;` on your parent element.

```css
 #wrapper {
   overflow: auto;
   width: 600px;
   border: 2px solid black;
 }
 
 #wrapper p {
   float: left;
   width: 200px;
   margin-left: 10px;
 }
 
 #wrapper img {
   float: right;
 }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <p>
    This image is taller than the element containing it, and it's floated, so it's overflowing outside of its container!
  </p>

  <img src="picture.jpg" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your clearfix class is wrong here. It should be

   wrapper .clearfix{
               clear:both;
               }

So you will clear the floats before and after.

2. You gotta apply `overflow:auto` to #wrapper

   wrapper{
           width:600px;
           border: 2px solid black;
           overflow: auto;
           }

Answer (score 0):

```css
#wrapper {
margin: 10px;
border: 2px solid #000;
background: #A00;
color: #FFF;
height:auto;
overflow:auto;
width:600px;
}
 #wrapper p{
        float:left;
        width:200px;
        margin-left:10px;
        }
#img{
float:right;
height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<p>
            This image is taller than the element containing it, and it's floated, so it's overflowing outside of its container! 
        </p>

    <div id="img"> <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_74so2YIdYpM/TEd09Hqrm6I/AAAAAAAAApY/rwGCm5_Tawg/s1600/tall+copy.jpg"    style="margin: 10px 10px; "/>

      </div>
    </div>
```