# Layout, content outside div container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to code a simple contact box. Unfortunately I can't get the layout right, alignments are wrong, and the "contact-content" text + image are outside of the second div container...

Here my code so far:

```css
div.contact {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.contact-heading {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 11px 20px;
}

.contact-heading-icon {
  float: right;
}

.contact-content {
  padding: 11px 20px;
}

.contact-content-text {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.contact-content-image {
  width: 170px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <div class="contact-heading">
    <p class="contact-heading-text">Kontakt</p>
    <img src="../images/icon-contact-person.png" alt="" class="contact-heading-icon" />
  </div>
  <div class="contact-content">
    <img src="../images/img-contact-person.png" alt="" class="contact-content-image" />
    <p class="contact-content-text">Your Contact<br><br>
      <b>Name Familyname</b><br> Company Name<br> Street City<br> T 123 123 45 67 89<br> email@company.com
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the image overflowing outside of the wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157754/why-is-the-image-overflowing-outside-of-the-wrapper)

Comment: what do you mean "alignments are wrong"? You need to tell us what's wrong and what you expect instead.

Comment: Like rob said, your contact info is outside of the parent because of a "clearfix" issue. There are tons of ways to solve that, including rob's link. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/bRgLbR

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `float: left;` on `.contact-content-text` and `.contact-content-image`

```css
div.contact {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.contact-heading {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 11px 20px;
}

.contact-heading-icon {
  float: right;
}

.contact-content {
  padding: 11px 20px;
}

.contact-content-text {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.contact-content-image {
  width: 170px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <div class="contact-heading">
    <p class="contact-heading-text">Kontakt</p>
    <img src="../images/icon-contact-person.png" alt="" class="contact-heading-icon" />
  </div>
  <div class="contact-content">
    <img src="../images/img-contact-person.png" alt="" class="contact-content-image" />
    <p class="contact-content-text">Your Contact<br><br>
      <b>Name Familyname</b><br> Company Name<br> Street City<br> T 123 123 45 67 89<br> email@company.com
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display: inline-block` to `.contact-content`

```css
div.contact {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.contact-heading {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 11px 20px;
}

.contact-heading-icon {
  float: right;
}

.contact-content {
  padding: 11px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.contact-content-text {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.contact-content-image {
  width: 170px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <div class="contact-heading">
    <p class="contact-heading-text">Kontakt</p>
    <img src="../images/icon-contact-person.png" alt="" class="contact-heading-icon" />
  </div>
  <div class="contact-content">
    <img src="../images/img-contact-person.png" alt="" class="contact-content-image" />
    <p class="contact-content-text">Your Contact<br><br>
      <b>Name Familyname</b><br> Company Name<br> Street City<br> T 123 123 45 67 89<br> email@company.com
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```